# Websockets/Socket.io How to delay updates until initial payload fetch is complete?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

node 5.4.0
socket.io: ^1.3.7

I'm unsure how to initialize data for a stream of posts while also setting a listener for updates(new posts).

**How I Currently Initialize The Stream:**

In my example below I have a client that first requests the initial payload and once the payload arrives it sets the listener to listen for updates.

I designed it that way so that push events for updates wouldn't happen
until the initial payload return.

**The Problem:**

As the response returns from the server there is a window of time 
where potential updates are missed(especially if the volume of updates is large).

**Question:**

Is there a way to handle the initial payload request and set the update listener without the possibility of missing updates or receiving them prematurally?

**Server Side- Sends out initial payload and updates when requested**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected to');
});

app.get('/initialData/',function(req, res){
  var initialPayload = fetchPayload();//fetch from db
  res.json(initialPayload);
}

app.post('/update',function(req, res){

  var updateData = req.body.json;
  updateData(update ,function(){
      var socket = io();
      socket.emit('update data', updateData);
      res.status(200).end();
    }
  });
});
```

**ClientSide- Calls for payload, an when succceeds sets listener**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var getInitialPayload = function() {
  var socketURL = "http://localhost:3000/"
    var socket = io(socketURL);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000';
    $.ajax({ 
      url: url,  
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(initialPayload) { 
       ServerActionCreators.receiveAllPayload(initialPayload);
        socket.on('update data', data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) { 
        //print error
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please do not confuse WebSockets and socket.io.    The former is a browser API that socket.io will use as its underlying transport mechanism _if it's available in your browser_ but the two are not the same thing.

Comment: So you deferred adding the listener so you wouldn't be notified of pending updates, and now you're complaining that you're missing updates? So rethink that decision. All you need here is some form of queue. Probably you shouldn't be using listeners at all.

Comment: @Alnitak, sorry I figured the premise of the question extended outside of socket.io and so I generalized it to include websockets as well.

Comment: @EJP Without deferment updates could be pushed too soon(causing duplicate information). With deferments some updates would be missed. That really is the core question - I can't see a way that both of these issues can be avoided.

Comment: Also - on the client side native `Promise` isn't supported on MSIE - are you using a shim?  You also never call the `resolve` or `reject` methods of that promise.  Plus, you can just pass `context: this` to `$.ajax` instead of using `.bind(this)` on those callbacks!

Comment: @Alnitak opps. Those binds were not needed for the simplified example. I removed them.